# python class weave numberrows together

Tags: python, class

I wrote the following class to weave multiple rows of number together, how do i print the result?

```
class NumberRow(object):

def __init__(self, row2):
    self.row = row2
    self.amount = len(row2)

def weave(self,other):
    lijst = []
    for i in range(self.amount):
        lijst.append(self.row[i])
        lijst.append(other.row[i]) 
    self.row = lijst
```

---

```
from ipy_lib import file_input
from number_row import NumberRow

'''program'''

bestand = file_input().splitlines()
lijst1 = bestand[0].split()
lijst2 = bestand[1].split()
lijst3 = bestand[2].split()

row1 = NumberRow(lijst1)
row2 = NumberRow(lijst2)
row3 = NumberRow(lijst3)

row1.weave(row2)
number_list = row1.weave(row3)

print number_list
```

I get a "NoneType" error. How can I make sure a class object becomes printable?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the connection between your code and your question, but to make an instance printable, you should define a `__str__` method, and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `weave` is not returning anything, so you need to modify code like this:

```
def weave(self,other):
    lijst = []
    for i in range(self.amount):
        lijst.append(self.row[i])
        lijst.append(other.row[i]) 
    self.row = lijst
    return self.row
```